# best-practice to display flash on Iphone / Ipad?

Tags: iphone, flash, ipad

I have a website that uses flash. I would like to convert the website so that iphone / ipad users can see my website. I understand that Iphone / Ipad can't render flash. What would be the best-practice to convert flash website to iphone / ipad compatible?

I am thinking HTML 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[tongue in cheek]

It's not that it "can't" render Flash, it's that it's not allowed to.

[/tongue in cheek]

For Flash Video, html5 has `<video>` tags. Bear in mind, though, that not all browsers support video tags.

For basic animation, javascript has come a long way.

I'm starting to think that html5 is the new buzzword. The old one was "Web 2.0"

Comment: +1 for `html5 is the new buzzword. The old one was "Web 2.0"`

Answer (score 0):

There's a brief example of someone porting a piece of Flash code into canvas/html5, here:

http://blog.mangrove.nl/?pageID=3&messageID=18436

I think the lesson is that it's possible, but there's not (yet) an automated method.

If you were starting from scratch, you could look at **haxe** which I understand can be used to create either Actionscript or Javascript code:

http://www.haxe.org

Hope this helps a bit.